# API Manager: Start up error - ConcurrentModificationException from CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask

Tags: wso2

On our single server, after a default install of WSO2 API Manager (1.6.0) we see a startup error: ConcurrentModificationException

```
TID: [0] [AM] [2014-01-02 11:02:15,313] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Error while running deployment scheduler..  {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask}
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:926)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:966)
        at java.util.HashMap$EntryIterator.next(HashMap.java:964)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.loadOtherDirectories(RepositoryListener.java:270)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:253)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.startListener(RepositoryListener.java:371)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.checkRepository(SchedulerTask.java:59)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.scheduler.SchedulerTask.run(SchedulerTask.java:67)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.runAxisDeployment(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:79)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.run(CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Any ideas how to solve this error? Is this a config issue in axis2.xml or carbon.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see this every time you start the API Manager? This has been reported as an intermittent problem, and is not due to a config issue. Please refer to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-14471 for more details.

Comment: Yes every time when AM is started. You are mentioning  a link, it saus it it fixed in a pacth; 4.2.0-patch0001 . Can I assume that it is not fixed in the AM 1.6.0 version? Where can I obtain this patch?

Comment: The patch is already included in the AM pack (there are several kernel patches released with AM 1.6.0. These can be found inside <APIM>/repository/components/patches folder). Do you get this problem on a fresh pack, or is it after changing any of the configs?

Comment: Look something on our side; teh OOTB installation with inemory database does not show this behaviour.